# A sequence of square matrices with lim (det) = 0 but condition number of 1

Tags: matrices, determinant

When the condition number of a matrix is $1$, it implies it is invertible (nonsingular) and hence its determinant is nonzero. Is this also true in the limit? Specifically, is there a sequence of square matrices with $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \det(M_n)=0$$ but with $\kappa_2(M_n)=1$  for all $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such a sequence. The condition number of the identity matrix $I$ is $1$, as is its determinant. Let 
$$M_n = \frac{1}{n}I.$$
Then $\det(M_n) = (1/n)^d$ where $d$ is the dimension. But $\kappa_2(M_n) = 1$ for all $n$, so this is an example of such a sequence.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of idempotent matrices, but couldn't verify it.

Comment: What is $\kappa_k(M)$ for a matrix?

Comment: @DietrichBurde After choosing a matrix norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ (e.g., the operator norm) it is $\kappa(A) = \Vert A \Vert \cdot \Vert A^{-1} \Vert$.